# Java declare array outside variable definition

Tags: java, arrays, declaration

I'm looking for a way to give a java array a value directly, outside of its declaration, for example

```
/*this works*/
int a[] = {1,2,3};

/*this doesn't*/
a = {1,2,3};
```

the motivation is so that a method with an array as an argument can be used like this

```
public void f(int a[]) {
 /*do stuff*/
}

f({1,2,3});
```

instead of

```
int a[] = {1,2,3};
f(a);
```

Comment: Do you mean a literal array? This seems to not have anything to do with statics

Comment: yes "literal array" is the term i was going for. i didn't know the proper name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
a = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 5):

try :

```
a = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

Comment: i declare my individuality via my lowercase t

Comment: and the lack of a space between ']' and '{'. i will allow our differences.

Answer (score 3):

In general you can say

```
int[] a;
a = new int[]{1,2,3};
```

```
public void f(int a[]) { ... }

f(new int[]{1,2,3})
```

to initialize arrays at arbitrary places in the code.

Answer (score 3):

As a cleaner alternate, you could use the variable parameters functionality, this still works with passing in an array too - it's just syntactic sugar.

```
public void f(int... a) {
    /*do stuff*/
}

public void test() {
    f(1);
    f(1,2,3);
    f(new int[]{1,2,3});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static block to do what you are looking for. Keep in mind that this is executing the first time the class is loaded.

```
private static int a[];

static {
    a = new int[] {1,2,3};
    f(new int[]{1,2,3}); 
}

public static void f(int a[]) {
 ///
}
```

Comment: Based on the responses, it looks like you are asking for declaring an array not a 'static' array.

Comment: "yes. i misused the word static" -- can you tell us the difference between static and reference? public void f(int a[]) gives you the actual array at the point of the method call, which you can then just use as the actual array.